# Calculating Nmax in loaded bipolar junction transistor inverter

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, npn, pn-junction, bipolar

I have tried various methods for calculating N max here, and some have resulted in negative answers while others have resulted in an answer of around 1.

Is my method correct? Or am I missing something in regard to what it means for Vo = Vol max?

The Question:
[image]

Equations that I used in my given attempt:
[image]

Attempt at part a:
[image]

I'm not sure if I should be including the forward current gain or the overdrive factor in my answer for part a. Are they acceptable as transistor parameters?

Attempt at parts b & c :
[image]

Comment: Hi, Peter. Why did you introduce the saturated collector-emitter voltage when developing an equation for (a)? I'm unclear about why. I do think you need to know the minimum "input-high" voltage required at the input: \$V_{\text{IH}_\text{MIN}}\$.

Comment: In your analysis, does \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}=V_{\text{OL}_\text{MAX}}\$? (Because, in my reading of your question and part (a), I believe that the intent is \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\ne V_{\text{OL}_\text{MAX}}\$.)